# Record Helper & Class Methods

Tags: delphi

```
TTransactionType = (ttNone, ttCash, ttCheck, ttDebit);

TTransactionTypeHelper = record helper for TTransactionType
public
  class function ToTransactionType(TranTypeDescription : string) : TTransactionType;
  function ToString(): string;
end;

function TTransactionTypeHelper.ToString: string;
begin
  case Self of
    ttCash:
      Result := 'Cash';
    ttCheck:
      Result := 'Check';
    ttDebit:
      Result := 'Debit'
  else
    Result := '';
  end;
end;

class function TTransactionTypeHelper.ToTransactionType(
  TranTypeDescription: string): TTransactionType;
begin
  if (TranTypeDescription = 'Cash') then
    Result := ttCash
  else if (TranTypeDescription = 'Check') then
    Result := ttCheck
  else if (TranTypeDescription = 'Debit') then
    Result := ttDebit
  else
    Result := ttNone;
end;
```

The class method, ToTransactionType is accessible via TTransactionTypeHelper (expected).

Is there a way to make method ToTransactionType accessible via the enumeration directly? e.g.,

```
TTransactionType.ToTransactionType('Cash');
```

Comment: It is. Just make it `static`.

Comment: My code sample above omits the static keyword, but including it does not make it part of the enum class TTransactionType. It is part of TTransactionTypeHelper.

Comment: I don't understand. You've shown your example and it works (Delphi Tokyo). Just that missing `static`. If you're asking whether an enumeration can have a method, then it is not possible would be the answer.

Comment: It works via the helper class (TTransactionTypeHelper) but not via the enum class (TTransactionType). We're trying to make it so everything is accessible via the enum itself rather than require accessing the helper directly.

Comment: You call that method on `TTransactionType` type, not `TTransactionTypeHelper` in your example. That is possible. The purpose of helpers is just that, extending types.

Comment: Apologies. The reason I thought it didn't work is that code completion doesn't display ToTransactionType as a valid method for TTransactionType. It does, however, compile and work properly.

Answer (score 2):

As @Victoria mentions in a comment, adding static to the `ToTransactionType` method, will make the call `TTransactionType.ToTransactionType('Cash')` work just fine.

If you want to extend the enumeration type without writing a helper, that is not possible. But there is another way:

Using RTTI and unit `TypInfo.Pas` you could call [GetEnumValue()](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.TypInfo.GetEnumValue):

```
var
  i : Integer;
  myTransactionValue : TTransactionType;
begin
  i := GetEnumValue(TypeInfo(TTransactionType),'ttCheck');
  if (i <> -1) then myTransactionValue := TTransactionType(i);
end;
```

---

There is also [GetEnumName()](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.TypInfo.GetEnumName):

```
s := GetEnumName(TypeInfo(TTransactionType),Ord(TTransactionType.ttCheck));  // s = 'ttCheck'
```